# InApp subscription for users with same Google Account

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I'm developing app that will have inApp subscriptions. And now I faced problem when user buys subscription for APP_USER_1 (for example), then logins into APP_USER_2 and he can't buy same subscription because he did it already for this Google Account (That he uses for Play Store).

I have thought about several solutions:

- Make subscription as consumable item and consume it right away (but this way there will be no such thing as auto-renewing)
- Give all items that is purchased for current Google Account to all App users that'll login (but it's not really OK)

So is there any way this problem can be solved in another way?

Comment: The subscriptions are connected to the google account through which the app was downloaded (or if that account is deleted, then to the new account through which the subscription was purchased). It is not linked with the users on the app. So if you want the subscription to be tied to a user (rather than a device/google account), then you might have to write your own billing service.